# Image not displaying in html, but displaying in browser

Tags: html

I have an image with URL
http://nba2kcontest.com/fantasy/img/player.png

It is visible when I directly go to this URL, but not when I use html img tag it is not displaying:

```
<img src="http://nba2kcontest.com/fantasy/img/player.png">
```

I don't know what is the problem because the permission is also 0777

### Edit

I don't know what but when I replace the picture `player.png` with `player.svg` it works!

Comment: Did you set any css for it?

Comment: Context please. Show the HTML for the page it's in. If it's a lot, them make a simple page with the IMG and try that. Then problem is likely not with the element itself.

Comment: Can you please give us more information? What about errors in your browsers developer console? Because it works like a charm: https://jsfiddle.net/vtp5wyqr/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the issue you are seeing. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so. Please also take a moment to read [ask] for what's expected on this site.

Answer (score -1):

Give the below a shot, maybe you have a background color set on a parent container that is making your png not visible.

```css
.img-container{
  background:#fff;
  padding:10px
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
<img src="http://nba2kcontest.com/fantasy/img/player.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Please use answers for answering the question, not for asking for clarification. You have enough reputation to comment; please use that.